# Flicker free console updates with virtual terminal sequences

Tags: terminal, console, escaping, buffer

In a C# console application for Windows, I'm am using the Windows Console API [WriteConsoleOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput) (via PInvoke) to write an entire buffer in a single operation to prevent flickering. This works fine.

[Microsoft recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/classic-vs-vt) using **virtual terminal sequences** to interact with the console. These sequences are great, as they offer much better output, such as colors, etc.

But, as I understand it, `WriteConsoleOutput` cannot be used with escape sequences (see [CHAR_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/char-info-str)).

My question is,

*How can I use virtual terminal sequences to write to the console flicker-free?*

I'd like to update different parts of the screen with different characters and colors. Doing this by chaining a lot of `Console.Write()` and `Console.SetCursorPosition` **will** cause a lot of flickering and reduce framerate.

*What is the virtual terminal equivalent of writing an entire buffer?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but I have found a solution after a couple of days' experimenting.

The answer to this question:

> What is the virtual terminal equivalent of writing an entire buffer?

There is none.
Not exactly.
I haven't found anything similar to [WriteConsoleOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput), which renders a pre-populated buffer of an arbitrary size.

However, virtual terminals have the concept of [alternate screen buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#alternate-screen-buffer), which can be created by [CreateConsoleScreenBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createconsolescreenbuffer) and switched with [SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleactivescreenbuffer).

Using that, I came up with a solution for my first question:

> How can I use virtual terminal sequences to write to the console flicker-free?

Basically, what I do is I create a new buffer and then use [WriteConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) to write VT escape sequences to the back buffer before I switch the buffers.

The thing I don't like about this solution is the call to `WriteConsole`. There will be a lot of them (writing characters/sequences one by one), or there will be few of them when writing long pre-escaped strings.

In order to test flickering, I created a single string with 120 x 30 characters, with each character given a [256-color](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797#256-colors). This produced a string of over 41'000 characters, which was used as input to `WriteConsole`.

This actually seems to work pretty well!

This is the best solution I have found so far. If you find a better one, please write your own answer here!